# Visual Studio 2022 Hot Reload for a Microsoft Visio VSTO Solution doesn't really work

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, visio, visual-studio-2022

Even though Microsoft says that the new hot reload functionality works for pretty much any .NET project, and Office VSTO is not mentioned as an exception, I assumed that hot reload would work pretty well.

However if I make even an insignificant change to any function in my ThisAddIn object, I get this error for pretty much any Visio interop object used in the function:

Error   BC37230 Cannot continue since the edit includes a reference to an embedded type: 'Shapes'.  ExtendedVisioAddin1     1   Active

I could add just this line:

Dim A as integer = 1

and I get these errors and hot reload isn't working.

Is hot reload incompatible with the .NET wrappers around COM interop objects? If I could get hot reload to work with Office VSTO solutions it would be a pretty great timesaver. Thank you for your help and advice!

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard about such features implemented for the unmanaged solutions like VSTO. Only standalone applications can be reloaded quickly (have got the hot-reload feature onboard).

Comment: The weird thing is Microsoft doesn't mention this as an exception for hot reload but does mention a whole bunch of other exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, that's a shame. We, developers, should validate everything ourselves. It is marketing!

Comment: When debugging a Visio VSTO it does show the hot reload button, then it doesn't work with the COM interop VSTO uses which is the whole point of VSTO solutions. Still some functions do not use any unmanaged COM objects I expect hot reload to work there in a VSTO solution, unfortunately of limited help.

Comment: I created some code in the addin that doesn't use ANY COM interop objects and hot reload DOES work there, so hot reload does have a (very) limited use for VSTO solutions.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, only the managed code can benefit from this feature.